# GUI tool for running testNG tests

Tags: java, testng

Is there any open source GUI tool/application where we can register testNG tests and do the operations like -

1. run specific set of tests just by selecting the tests using mouse
2. view the result in the one of the panel in the same GUI ?

Any inputs / suggestions are appreciated !

Comment: http://testng.org lists plugins for Eclipse, NetBeans and Idea - don't they provide that functionality?

Comment: TestNG eclipse plugin displays the tests only after running them, but is there an option to display the tests just after compilation and I could pick tests for execution manually from Eclpise TestNG explorer?

Answer (score 3):

http://testng.org lists plugins for Eclipse, NetBeans and Idea.

Screenshot of the one for Eclipse seems to be what you need:
[image]

Comment: This looks cool! I will checkit out!!  I think this helps for automation engineers. What I am really looking out for is similar kind of UI which should be given ( may be url or something) to the People who doesn't / don't want to bother of about installing / technical details ? just imagine , I need to provide a URL to higher management something like http:/nice_ui.com where they can run the tests and view the results themselves!!

Comment: Hi. Don't know about your management people, but mine do not care about running tests themself :-). Wouldn't you be actually looking for a tool that could give them metrics and info about the global code quality ? Something like... Sonar ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution doesn't have checkboxes like csUnit has.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins provides a [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/testng-plugin) for TestNG.  Using this, anyone can create the build, deploy and test your application and also check the reports on a web based UI.  All this in the latest build and everything is web-based with good graphical reports.

Comment: Hi, Using this plugin we can only trasport the testNG result file onto the jenkins UI! Is there some other plugin / some configuration if enabled/installed would seek the testng test annotations onto the jenkins UI?  so that it would be easier for me to just select the required test groups ( on the jenkins UI itself) and run those tests only ?  any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes.  Please have a look at [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/testng-plugin).

Comment: Thanks Bala for responding. As I described above (about testNG plugIn), it doesn't help! Any other Plugins ?

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated! Are there any other plugins which would seek the testng test annotations onto the jenkins UI?

Comment: @chandra_shekar were you able to find any solution for this? I'm also looking for similar option and any input would really help me.